# How can I tell if a relation was just deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there something like `#saved_changes` that will tell me when a relation was destroyed? The destruction happens via `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

I have a processing pipeline that my object goes through after being saved, and that pipeline needs to know if a relation was destroyed. Unfortunately, when I call `my_obj.images` after destroying the image, `#image` is an empty array.

I haven't found a "images before destruction" method. I suspect that I have to look at the object before committing the change and set a flag on it that something is being destroyed. I'd really like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: In image model why not use `after_destroy` callback and push the deleted entry to separate table say `deleted_entity`. 
Another approach could be on delete do a soft delete i.e. flag the entry as deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have needed this more than once, so I wrote a gem for it:

https://github.com/brandoncc/activerecord-nested_attribute_destruction

Here is a usage example:

```rb
class Harbor
  has_many :ships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ships, allow_destroy: true
end

harbor.ships_attributes = [harbor.ships.first.attributes.merge('_destroy': true)]
harbor.save!

harbor.ships_destroyed_during_save? # true
```

See that last line of code? That is what the gem adds :smiley: